# Request Read Receipt with Python/Exchangelib?

Tags: exchangelib

My first post so please excuse any ignorance on my part. I have had great success with email automation using Exchangelib. I am curious to know if there is a configuration option to request a read or delivery receipt?

I have spent the last few days researching options but not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the `Message.is_read_receipt_requested` boolean field. When set to True, you will get a read receipt when the `is_read` field of the received message is set to True, unless the receiver explicitly disabled sending read receipts.

Comment: Thanks Erik! I will give this a try and report back.